# strange PDO behaviour

Tags: php, pdo

After some hours I have to post this question even if the answer maybe obvious to someone else.

The problem is that I want to test for the tokens, but even when I hardcode this, I still get INVALID. And I know it has to be right, because I tested it in PHPADMIN directly. What's odd is that it always passes the first time (without being hardcoded), but after that it is useless?
The tokens are retrieved from a cookie.

```
public function findTriplet($credential, $token, $persistentToken) {

    $token = "459078a3b05ce938ed58f9678ac78f1agcgfsewe4";
    $persistentToken = "24d317b742da89ddf5b8ed50993d0f3cgcgfsewe4";
    $credential ="34";
    $q = "SELECT IF(SHA1(?) = {$this->tokenColumn}, 1, -1) AS token_match " .
         "FROM {$this->tableName} WHERE {$this->credentialColumn} = ? " .
         "AND {$this->persistentTokenColumn} = SHA1(?) LIMIT 1 ";
    $query = $this->db->prepare($q);
    $query->execute(array($token, $credential, $persistentToken));
    $result = $query->fetchColumn();

    if (!$result) {
        return self::TRIPLET_NOT_FOUND;
    } else if ($result == 1) {
        return self::TRIPLET_FOUND;
    } else {
        return self::TRIPLET_INVALID; }
    }
```

**EDIT**

*The limit clause always catches the first row it finds, therefore I
always get a mismatch Now I have to fix this.*

The solution was simple. Delete the entry that was just validated before inserting a new row with the newly generated token. The new row should contain the SAME persistenceToken you just validated against. REMEMBER, this will still be UNSECURE, so set a FLAG on the serverside that this was a cookielogin, and require a REAL LOGIN for handling important data.

Comment: I'm guessing the `$result";` is a copy & paste error? (syntax error)

Comment: Stuff like this can be only sorted through debugging - systematically analyzing every step the code makes, the values present, and the queries sent. It's standard fare for every programmer

Comment: how can I debug this? Ok, I haven't actually tried to test for one value, if it fails I am going to scream

Comment: Are you sure you want to `SHA1(something-that-looks-like-a-sha1-hash-already);`?

Comment: You should look closer at `if ($result == 1)`, I doubt this behaves as you expect.

Comment: `var_dump($result)` - look at the value you get there, then you'll know if the problem is above or below that line.

Comment: @Wrikken, was result of strand + salt

Answer (score 1):

I think your `if` checks are in the wrong order:

```
    if(!$result) {  return self::TRIPLET_NOT_FOUND;}
    elseif ($result == 1) {     return self::TRIPLET_FOUND;}
    else {  return self::TRIPLET_INVALID;}
```

In the SQL, 1 means found, -1 means not found, and anything else would be invalid. But in the PHP, a -1 would fall into the `else` clause, and return `self::TRIPLET_INVALID`, whereas an invalid result would fall into `if(!$result)` and return `self::TRIPLET_NOT_FOUND`.

Comment: I am thinking about it, I thought of it like "invalid" is it matched on all columns except the tokenColumn, maybe you are right. I am a little bit tripping right now. I am gonna eat my soup now.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Maybe I misunderstood the intent.

Comment: anyway, it must be something incredibly obvious, so I will start over with one parameter at a time,I will let you know